# strtotime() different outputs for today's time

Tags: php, date, strtotime

In PHP , i've used the following code :

```
echo strtotime("today")."<br>";
echo strtotime("06/08/2011")."<br>";
```

I'm getting two different outputs :O

Why is that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different outputs because the second one is not today, as you think. The second date is read actually as 08 June 2011.

If you write this code:

```
echo date("d M Y @ H:i", strtotime("today"))."<br/>";
echo date("d M Y @ H:i", strtotime("06/08/2011"))."<br/>";
```

You can see what I'm saying.

The second line should be:

```
strtotime("08/06/2011");
```

Answer (score 1):

`06/08/2011` is being interpreted as month-day-year, so `June 8th, 2011`.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because in some locales "6/8/2011" means "June 8", and in other locales it means "August 6".

For me (in the U.S.), it means "June 8".

Here's the PHP documentation which discusses setlocale() and LC_TIME:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime("today");` is getting the exact time it is right now.

You can run `time()` to get the same result.

`strtotime("06/08/2011")` is getting the time at midnight (`00:00`) of the day you specified.
By the way, the day you specified is June 08, 2011.  PHP doesn't handle dd/mm/yyy by default.  You would have to specify that that's your locale default setting.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on PHP version:

- in PHP 4.4.6: "today" is identical to "now", actual datetime
- in PHP 5.1.4: "today" means the midnight of today

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#77541)